# How to use mix of remote and local filtering on a store?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a scenario in which I want to use remoteFilter for grid column filter and local filtering for a textbox provided in toolbar on the same store. Can anyone suggest a better way to do this?

Please let me know if you need more inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I think in ExtJs up to 4.x, this is not possible. Either the store uses local filtering or remote filtering, but not both.

In ExtJs 5, there is the possibility to chain stores. You could have store A with remote filtering, and have store B based on store A, with local filtering.  Your grid would be bound to store B. Disclaimer : I never used this feature yet.

A workaround is possible : instead of loading the data automatically into the store (`autoLoad: false`) , you can do it by sending the remote filter parameters with `store.load({params: ... })`, and configure the store with local filtering.